# Passing an object as a parameter in a method

Tags: c#, wcf

I am working on a C# project.
I have a Nameclass class with some properties(first name, lastname).
In dept class I have instatiated the Nameclass  and assigned some values to firstname and lastname.
Now in dept class I am calling another method setValues() which belongs to Order class.
In this method I am passing this NameClass and some other vlaues.
The code looks like this.

```
Order.setValues(nameObject, address, city, state,zip)
```

Now in Order Class when when I am trying to access the properties from
nameObject Its not showing any properits.
Why I am not getting the firstname and last name values here in Order class.
Do I have to instantiate the NameClass again in Order class inorder to get the properties.
I appreciate if you can tell me what mistake I am doing here.

Comment: we need to see how the various classes are defined

Comment: Show a code of classes which you've mentioned

Comment: It's impossible to say. However, the most likely problem here is that the `nameObject` is being passed as an `object` or other type instead of the actual type. Thus, there is no way to know what properties / fields it actually has. You should post your implementation of `Order.setValues` in order for us to be able to evaluate why that is occuring.

Comment: All classes are regular classes where as Order.setValues() is a static method.

Comment: share you code so that we can understand axactly what you are talking abuot bc if we are passing values in object that are available us untill the Accessciblity don't stop them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the reason this is happening is because your `Order.setValues()` method has the following signature:

`public static void setValues(object nameObject, string address, string city, string state, string zip)`

If my estimation is correct then the answer is simple. Your object is being treated as an type object rather than as type `NameClass`. You can't know at compile-time what properties are inside a base class object short of Reflextion.

Solution would be to simply change the type of nameObject parameter in your method to type `NameClass`  ... all this is assuming my assumption is correct.

Comment: Thank you. Yes My signature is wrong. I really appreciated all your help. This is a great Forum.

Answer (score 2):

You're not showing your code, but there are a few possibilities, including:

1. Make sure that your `setValues` method is passing the first parameter using the proper type, ie:  `void setValues(NameClass name, string address, ...`, and not using `void setValues(object name, ...`.
2. Make sure that the properties or fields in `NameClass`  (`firstname` and `lastname`) are not marked `private`, but are instead `public` (or `internal` if you're in the same project).

Comment: I neglected to considered option #2 =P

Answer (score 0):

You've either declared the parameter as type object, or the data members are not public.  In the former case, there's no way for VC# to know what members are in your object.